# Can't install twisted behind corporate proxy (without internet)

Tags: twisted

I am trying to install twisted (something that depends on twisted 20.3.0) on a machine which has no internet access, using internal Pypi mirror repository. The issue is that during installation of twisted, it manually tries to connect to pypi.org to download its dependencies, instead of relying on pip that I already set up to use the internal mirror.

How can I install twisted this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: I have to manually install incremental>=16.10.1 for twisted==20.3.0 and this way it doesn't try to download anything from pypi.org. I had to install it separately, it didn't work if it was part of requirements.txt:

```
pip3 install --index-url $PRIVATE_REPO --extra-index-url $PRIVATE_REPO2 incremental>=16.10.1
pip3 install --index-url $PRIVATE_REPO --extra-index-url $PRIVATE_REPO2 -r app/requirements.txt
```

According to the developers this should fix it:  ~/.pydistutils.cfg:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = https://corporate-pypi-mirror/simple/
```